# Estilo CSS a radioButton

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando aplicar estilo `CSS`a unos radiobutton. Quiero que cuando este `input` esté `checked` la etiqueta `label`se ponga de color verde. Sin embargo con el código que yo utilizo se ponen verde las posteriores, y no la que he pulsado ni las anteriores.

```css
.posicionesDeportes label{cursor: pointer;}
.posicionesDeportes input{display: none;}
.posicionesDeportes label:hover {color: #ecc300;}
.radio-custom:checked ~ label  {color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="posicionesDeportes col-md-3 form-group">
   <span class="selectPos1">Equipo A</span><br>
   <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="porteroA">Portero</label>
   <input id="porteroA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="porteroA" required><br>
   <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="centralA">Central</label>
   <input id="centralA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="centralA"><br>
   <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="alaIzqA">Ala izquierda</label>
   <input id="alaIzqA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="alaIzqA"><br>
   <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="alaDerA">Ala derecha</label>
   <input id="alaDerA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="alaDerA"><br>
   <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="pivotA">Pívot</label>
   <input id="pivotA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="pivotA"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es con la regla `.radio-custom:checked ~ label  {color:green;}`
 estás diciendo que tome cualquier hermano (hermano posterior, en **CSS** no podemos seleccionar elementos anteriores en el **DOM**) de un elemento `.radio-custom` que esté seleccionado y que sea `<label>`, para colocarle el color verde.

**¿Qué es lo que ocurre?** Que en tu **HTML** cualquier `<label>` posterior al `.radio-custom` que pulses, cumple con esta regla, volviéndose verde.

Una manera de solucionarlo es metiendo cada pareja de `.radio-custom` + `<label>` dentro de un contenedor, para afectar solamente al que nos interesa. Esto seguiría sin darnos la solución, ya que el `<label>` al que queremos afectar se encuentra antes del `<input>` que lo cambia. Con intercambiar sus posiciones te bastaría.

```css
.posicionesDeportes label{cursor: pointer;}
.posicionesDeportes input{display: none;}
.posicionesDeportes label:hover {color: #ecc300;}
.radio-custom:checked + label  {color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="posicionesDeportes col-md-3 form-group">
  <span class="selectPos1">Equipo A</span><br>
  <div class="grupo-radio">
    <input id="porteroA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="porteroA" required>
    <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="porteroA">Portero</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grupo-radio">
    <input id="centralA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="centralA">
    <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="centralA">Central</label>
  <div>
  <div class="grupo-radio">
    <input id="alaIzqA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="alaIzqA">
    <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="alaIzqA">Ala izquierda</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grupo-radio">
    <input id="alaDerA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="alaDerA">
    <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="alaDerA">Ala derecha</label>
  </div>
  <div class="grupo-radio">
    <input id="pivotA" class="radio-custom" type="radio" name="equipo" value="pivotA">
    <label class="fas fa-futbol" for="pivotA">Pívot</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como añadido, eliminé los `<br>`. Hay que evitarlos en la medida de lo posible y teniéndolos dentro de `<div>` no habría problema con el salto de línea.